# How do you reverse a portion of an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reverse

`var foo = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];`

How would you turn the above into something like below?

`var rev = [0, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9];`

As you can see `rev` is only partially reversed. The reverse operation started at index `2` and ended at index `5`

*Just to make the end result clearer to see:*

`var foo = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];`

`var rev = [0, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9];`

Answer (score 0):

```
var foo = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
```

Copying a portion of foo array starting at index 2 until just before index 6:

```
var bar = foo.slice(2,6);
bar.reverse();
```

Splice out the portion you'd like from foo, and insert bar in its place:

```
foo.splice(2, 4, bar)
```

Flatten array:

```
var rev = [].concat.apply([], foo);
```

Comment: Credit goes to Nikita Volkov for showing me how to flatten an array in JavaScript: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15397506/2359049

Comment: Why did you ask a question and then answer yourself 5 mins later?

Comment: @JohanP because it's encouraged by the inventor of this website

Comment: @JaromandaX yeah, that's a good note, I didn't want to distract from the message, but people should be made aware.

Comment: @NYCTechEngineer I'm confused, did you actually want this solved or did you already have a solution, you just wanted to post a question and then show people the solution?

Comment: @JohanP yeah, why not?

Comment: Are you kidding me? You think this is a place to showcase solutions that no one has asked for?

Comment: @JohanP If the inventor of the website says it's okay to do, I'm going to assume it's okay to do.

Comment: @JohanP ah, well, simply a matter of bad UX, the checkbox to answer your own question should have been greyed out for 48 hours.

Comment: @JohanP Wait, I haven't accepted my own answer yet, and wasn't intending to until a few days have passed. So essentially, I have done nothing wrong at all if you read that link you shared with me.

Comment: @JohanP my point about bad UX earlier still stands if the website allows users to accept their own answers before the 48 hour limit.

Comment: @Nisarg sorry, I didn't realize you were talking to him, wasn't thinking straight for a moment.

Comment: I knew you could self answer questions but I have always thought that the reason why that is done is because you have an actual question that you need answering then after finding a solution, you accept it. I have never thought you can just post a question even tho you already know the answer.

Comment: Seems like it leaves the system open for abuse, unless you get no reputation for self accepting your answers

Comment: @JohanP I think it's a win win: you can self-document your own answers and share it with the community at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid mutating the original array:

```js
function reversePartArray(array, begin, length) {
    array = array.slice();
    array.splice(begin, length, ...array.slice(begin, begin+length).reverse());
    return array;
}
var foo = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var rev = reversePartArray(foo, 2, 4);
console.log(foo+'');
console.log(rev+'');
```

or

```js
function reversePartArray(array, begin, length) {
    array = array.slice();
    array.splice(begin, 0, ...array.splice(begin,length).reverse());
    return array;
}
var foo = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var rev = reversePartArray(foo, 2, 4);
console.log(foo+'');
console.log(rev+'');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good old iterative solution:

```js
let foo = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

let reverse = (array, start, end) => {
  while (start < end) {
    let t = array[start];
    array[start++] = array[end];
    array[end--] = t;
  }
};

reverse(foo, 2, 5);

console.log(foo.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just map the values with a check if the wanted reversed range is reached.

```js
var array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    start = 2,
    end = 5,
    result = array.map((v, i, a) => i >= start && i <= end ? a[end - i + start] : v);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```